# How to find $\int \frac{2x}{x^4+1}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Can you give me a hint how to start solving this?
$$\int \frac{2x}{x^4+1} dx$$

Comment: Substitute $u = x^2$.

Comment: @julien: Why is it _compute_ instead of _solve_?

Comment: @air_wizardo Think of solving as if you're finding the value of something.  Computing is taking an expression and making it simpler.

Comment: @anorton: Computing is simplifying???

Comment: @anorton Actually, when you compute something, you're often finding the value of something: compute 2 + 2? At any point, there was no need to edit the term.

Comment: @air_wizardo ehh... I stand corrected.  See amWhy's comment just above this.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not native speaker, so I am of course not an authority. In French, you compute an integral, definite or not, while you solve an equation. I've already seen people edit in this direction here on MSE, so that's why I thought it was the same in English.

Comment: @air_wizardo I hope you did not see my edit like an aggression. If was purely friendly. Like I said, above, I've seen "solve" edited (in the same context) for "compute" once, and I concluded it was ok to do so. Now I don't know. So I have asked [this question on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9060/solve-compute-evaluate-when-should-we-use-these-verbs) you might be interested in. Don't hesitate to give your input there! Google seems to prefer "compute integrals".

Comment: @julien: I totally understand. I was just curious.

Comment: I would say "evaluate an integral", but "solve an equation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use substitution 
$$
u = x^2.
$$
so that 
$$
du = 2xdx
$$

Answer (score 5):

If we set $\color{red}{\bf u = x^2}$, then $\color{blue}{\bf du = 2x\,dx}$

$$\int \frac{2x}{x^4 + 1} dx = \int \frac{\color{blue}{\bf 2x}}{(\color{red}{\bf x^2})^2+1}\, \color{blue}{\bf dx} = \int \frac{1}{\color{red}{\bf u}^2 + 1} \,\color{blue}{\bf du} $$

Review your integrals to find the integral, given this form.

Hint: Can you recall the function $f(u)$ whose derivative is equal to $$f'(u) = \dfrac{1}{u^2 + 1}\;?$$

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to book mark this reference: [Trig substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution). You'll find it handy to refer to when encountering problems similar to this.

Comment: Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice references in the comments too +1

Answer (score 2):

Find a way to apporach this from: 
$$(\arctan x)'=\frac{1}{x^2+1} $$

Comment: sorry...not read the request clearly... i will edit it